# adding foreign key from other table based on column values of first table - MySql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am new to mysql

I have two Tables in my database.

1. **id_details_table**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `id_details_table` (
>   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `CNIC` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```

sample record

```
INSERT INTO `id_details_table` (`ID`, `CNIC`) VALUES
(1, '3230328119795'),
(2, '4200004873681'),
(3, '4230188867895'),
(4, '3740566124323'),
(5, '4220191179125');
```

2. **mobiles_sim_details**

> ```
> >  CREATE TABLE `mobiles_sim_details` (  
> `Mobile` double DEFAULT NULL, 
> > `CNIC` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `id_cnic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL )
> > ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```

sample Record for table

```
INSERT INTO `mobiles_sim_details` (`Mobile`, `CNIC`, `id_cnic`) VALUES
(3000651082, '3230328119795', 0),
(3040877459, '4200004873681', 0),
(3013329415, '4230188867895', 0),
(3028590340, '3740566124323', 0),
(3000720166, '4220191179125', 0);
```

2 columns **CNIC** are present in both tables
Now What I want is, where there is 0 in the 2nd table I want it to be auto filled with the relevant ID from table 1 based on the data of CNIC from 2nd table.

I have tried this query but it didn't worked

```
UPDATE `mobiles_sim_details` SET `id_cnic`='[value-3]' WHERE (SELECT id FROM id_details_table WHERE CNIC = mobiles_sim_details.CNIC);
```

How can i Acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE mobiles_sim_details t1
JOIN id_details_table t2 USING (CNIC)
SET t1.id_cnic = t2.id
```